# How can CouchDB know the revision history of a document?

Tags: couchdb, document, revision

Let's assume there are two databases being replicated, A and B. Database A owns a document with four revisions. The revision tree looks like this:

```
   +--- r2a --- r3a
  /
r1----- r2b
```

The current leaf revisions are obviously `r3a` and `r2b`. According to the docs, only these revisions are transferred during replication. So database B is going to see this:

```
 r3a

 r2b
```

How can database B know the history of these revisions? As far as I know, the only information being copied are the both revisions without any notions about their parents. I'm I wrong?

**UPDATE: Why should database B know the history?**

Think about more changes to database A after the first replication. Each branch could be ammended by another revision. The revision tree would look like this:

```
   +--- r2a --- r3a --- r4a
  /
r1----- r2b --- r3b
```

Let's do another replication from A to B. How can database B know, that `r4a` is an descendant of `r3a` and therefore `r3a` is no longer a leaf revision. (Same with `r3b` and `r2b`.) In other words: How can database B be in this state:

```
 r3a --- r4a

 r2b --- r3b
```

instead of this state (all leaf revisions):

```
 r3a
 r4a
 r2b
 r3b
```

Comment: Why do you think database B would know the history of these revisions?

Comment: Thank you @Kerr. I've updated my question in order explain, why it's important for B to know the history of A. Probably the problem can be solved in another way – all the more, I'd be grateful to understand exactly how.

Comment: This is actual an interesting question. After reading your question I was all set to give an answer similar to Dominic's, but thought I might be missing something. I think it's something to do with how revision history is handled separately from the revisions themselves. I'm try to find out exactly how that works.

Answer (score 2):

The "revisions" you see in CouchDB are **not** a version control mechanism. They are purely used for a technique called [Multiversion Concurrency Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) (or MVCC), which allows concurrent access to the database without implementing locks.

The name "revision number" does seem to indicate that it can be used to trace down the history of a document, but that is not the case. As you have already identified, not all revisions are replicated. In addition, when you compact your database, all non-current revisions are deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I elaborated on my question, as there are still remaining aspects I unfortunately do not understand. I'd be very grateful, if you could again share your thoughts about it.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of CouchDB 2 includes a detailed description of the replication algorithm. There is the simple answer: The revision history *is* transmitted during replication. You can read it here: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/replication/protocol.html#upload-batch-of-changed-documents

Answer (score 0):

> How can database B know, that r4a is an descendant of r3a and therefore r3a is no longer a leaf revision.

Because r4a has the same ID as r3a - they differ in their revision ID not their document ID, so it is very clear that r4A is a newer revision of the same document?

Comment: r4b, r3a and r3b all have the same id. Based on the id, r4b could be a descendant of each of the two r3 revisions.